# PDF to text conversion without loosing formatting

Tags: pdftotext

When i am converting a pdf with some format to txt, i am getting all the text towards left.

Is there any code to convert pdf to txt with the same format as in the pdf?

Comment: PDF to word would retain your formatting. Text im afraid not able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to parse the location of the text characters from your PDF, you can probably achieve some formatting by inserting spaces or indents.

I know that the LEADTOOLS SDK, which what I am familiar with since I work for the vendor, has a `DocumentConverter` class that produces a formatted TXT output from an input PDF with the formatting roughly achieved as described above.

The code for this would look like this:

```
using (DocumentConverter documentConverter = new DocumentConverter())
{
   var inFile = @"Input.pdf";
   var outFile = Path.Combine(@"Output.txt");

   var docWriter = new DocumentWriter();
   var textOptions = docWriter.GetOptions(DocumentFormat.Text) as TextDocumentOptions;
   textOptions.DocumentType = TextDocumentType.Ansi;
   textOptions.AddPageNumber = true;
   textOptions.AddPageBreak = true;
   textOptions.Formatted = true;
   docWriter.SetOptions(DocumentFormat.Text, textOptions);
   documentConverter.SetDocumentWriterInstance(docWriter);

   var format = DocumentFormat.Text;
   var jobData = DocumentConverterJobs.CreateJobData(inFile, outFile, format);
   jobData.JobName = "conversion job";
   var job = documentConverter.Jobs.CreateJob(jobData);

   documentConverter.Jobs.RunJob(job);
}
```

As an example, here is how the output text for the conversion of a page in a PDF would look like:

The Input:
[image: Input PDF]

The Output:
[image: Output TXT]